# Mysql multiple simultaneous insert into queries

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-insert

I need to insert data into a set of columns in `data_table` (table 1) from `alarm_status_log_table` (table 2, the whole thing), and another set of data into `data_table` (table 1) from `channel` table (table 3, just name and description), thus completing `data_table` (table 1).

But the problem is, the name & description columns which I need to pass onto [data_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Xku.jpg) must be on the same row as the `alarm_id` they correspond with. That `alarm_id` is the same as the `channel_id` from the `channel` table which happens to already have the name and description that I want to send to data_table.

Basically I want to say:

```
Insert (name, description) from channel(table 3) into data_table(name, description) where channel_id = alarm_id
```

How can I proceed?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make an update JOIN like this:

```
UPDATE data_table a 
INNER JOIN table3 b ON a.alarm_id = b.channel_id
SET a.name=b.name, a.description=b.description
```

If you do not want to update, can you just join the tables? Maybe it would be better to create a joined view; this would avoid having redundant inconsistent data.

Comment: the problem is that the name and the description in the `channel` table must be ordered in the `data_table` in such a way that they correspond to the `alarm_id` so if 1st alarm is number 213, the name linked to `channel_id` 213 in `channel` must be `channel 1 temp` on the first row. A joined view is not going to give me that unless i am wrong.

Comment: here is something i came up with, creating the `device_status_log` table, using the `INNER JOIN` query:
`SELECT channel.channel_id, channel.name, channel.description
FROM channel

INNER JOIN device_status_log

ON channel.channel_id = device_status_log.alarm_id;`

This sorts them in the correct order but now, i need to put them altogether in that order in the fields attributed to the name and description on my final table.

Answer (score 0):

All i needed to do was to use a VIEW, since reordering data coming from two tables into a third table is quite tricky, here is the script i used to get the view i wanted:

`SELECT channel.name, channel.description, alarm_status_log.*
FROM data2desk.alarm_status_log
LEFT JOIN data2desk.channel ON channel.channel_id=alarm_status_log.alarm_id`

And it did the trick :)

[final view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcbDo.jpg)